# Is training Force sensitives really necessary for developing their abilities?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

From what we have seen with Rey and also

> Baby Yoda in *The Mandalorian*

it looks like they have *a lot* of Force abilities (and even some strong ones at that) without having received any formal training.

Thus I'm wondering, aside from promoting one side of the Force above the other, is training a Force sensitive really necessary for him/her to develop his/her abilities?

Comment: Or you know, they could just be rare natural prodigies.

Comment: It used to be. Then they retconned the hell out of it and now anyone's a Jedi if they want to be

Comment: Or come from a race/bloodline that's naturally powerful in the Force. I also have fanon that, when there are fewer Sith/Jedi, they find it easier to just develop abilities as the Force is less diluted amongst them and/or because the Force doesn't want information to be lost because they last person to know it died.

Comment: Mozart was composing piano pieces at age 5, but that doesn't stop composition from being something *most* of us need to study extensively before we can accomplish anything - if we ever can.

Comment: @suchiuomizu anakin was also said to be one....as was luke....and...they NEEDED training

Comment: Anakin's Force abilities made him capable of fighting capital ships at like 8 years old. Fairly prodigious. If anything, situating Luke against other canonical characters suggests him to be a slow learner or late bloomer, albeit strong once he got going.

Comment: @Adamant enhancing physical abilities / foresight was also something luke had (and a bit of telekinesis babies in the clone wars).  as he was able to shoot wompa rats from a speeding speeder. What is though is that  we see them useforce powers like entering the minds of others, or force chockes without any prior training. same for force lightning (although one can argue that there WAS a bit of training before that already). Thus I'm a bit questioninng there what is possible with and without trining and what is the sense of training at all there.